# Virtual Wifi Bridge

Tags: vpn, wifi

Let's say I have locationX, and I am in locationY (they're separated  200km).

Now locationX has WiFi's which are necessary to test mobile applications. (these WiFi's are used to communicate with devices - so, mobile app connects to WiFi using username & password, then sends request to 192.168.1), this is working nicely.

Now, I would like to test the mobile application myself as well. How do I access these WiFi's through locationY?

I need to create "fake" wifi, which would exist on locationY, and then which would proxy all the requests to locationX through VPN (??),

is there a name for what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to emulate wifi connection for testing purposes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563370/android-simulate-wifi-in-the-emulator
But if you want to test it properly, you would need the same set of WiFi APs as in locationX. Its also possible to configure one AP with multiple SSIDs, each with specific (same) frequency(2,4/5 GHz) protocol (802.11b/g/n/ac) and encryption (WEP/WPA/WPA2).
Either way, you would need to set up a VPN bridge - on device or router.